# altering the htaccess file of my WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need help altering the htaccess file of my WordPress site to all me to add new variables to the end of every url.

Like i want to add /es/ to the end of my WordPress URLs

Please guide they way i can do it

i tried 
custom paramlink like below but it did not worked

```
/%post_id%/es/
```

Comment: This can not be done with .htaccess, because wordpress will process it's own urls. By adding things to the url, we can still sent the urls to wordpress, but wordpress will not recognize them. You likely need to change wordpress settings.

Comment: If your idea is to have language specific versions of your website, then that isn't a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, you cannot accomplish this with .htaccess.

It looks like what you want to do is add an endpoint to your posts:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'es', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
```

The above code will add the `es` endpoint to your posts and pages. Make sure you flush your rewrite rules (by visiting the permalinks settings page) after adding that line, otherwise it won't have any affect.

You could then check if the endpoint is in use like this:

```
global $wp_query;
if(isset( $wp_query->query_vars['es'] )) {
    ...
}
```

If your end goal is to localize your site, I recommend you using something like [WPML](https://wpml.org) instead.